# How to specify opentelemetry configuration file path

Tags: configuration-files, open-telemetry, telemetry

I want to filter some endpoints and omit them from telemetry. I put opentelemetry-javaagent.jar in project folder and specify path in JAVA_OPTS variable. I run my application with next parameters:

```
JAVA_OPTS = -javaagent:/Users/...../Desktop/myProject/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar -Dotel.service.name\=MyApp -Dotel.tracer.exporter\=logging -Dotel.metrics.exporter\=logging -Dconfig.file=/Users/...../Desktop/myProject/config.yaml
```

All works fine, I see all requests in Graphana, but I want to exclude some endpoints from telemetry. I specify these endpoints in config.yaml and specify path to it in JAVA_OPTS. config.yaml is next:

```
processors:
  filter:
    spans:
      exclude:
        match_type: regexp
        services:
          - MyApp
        span_names:
          - *
```

After I run my app it still trace all endpoints but I expect that nothing will be traced. Looks like config.yaml doesn't accepted. What's wrong in my config? Thnks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official docs](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/java/automatic/), yaml configuration is not supported for java auto-instrumentation.
You can use `.properties` file by providing this option: `-Dotel.javaagent.configuration-file=path/to/properties/file.properties`.

A list of the supported properties can be found [here](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/java/automatic/agent-config/).

Please note, that there is no `filter` processor mentioned in the Java docs.
So you probably should add filtering logic to the [OpenTelemetry Collector](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/collector/) configuration.